# Паттерн репозиторий для entity framework Core. Есть вопросы

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core

Всегда использовал паттерн репозиторий, но больше как обертку которая нужна была для юнит-тестов, можно было встроить туда кеширование через Декоратор и еще какой нибудь декарируемый функционал, ну и все, больше никаких выгод я не видел.

Мои сомнения и вопросы по поводу классической реализации паттерна:

1. Зависимость от контекста есть не только в проекте, где используется слой доступа к данным (конкретный репозиторий для конкретной технологии хранения),
     но и в основном проекте где контекст Ef приходилось регистрировать в DI. Чтобы потом репозиторий получил контекст в конструкторе.
     Это же странно? Идеология подразумевает использовать абстрактный репозиторий как универсальный доступ к данным, например 10 хранилищ реализуют IGenericDataRepository и у каждого хранилища (проекта) свои зависимости и своя модель хранения данных. 
     То есть контекст EFCore должен использоваться только внутри проекта который реализует систему хранения на технологии EFCore.
     единственная связь с внешним миром это настройки и строка подключения.
     Но в основном все используют именно такой вариант паттерна репозитория (даже приводится пример на офф сайте EFCore).
2. Некоторые наружу выставляли IQuerible а не Ienumerable - тогда зачем что то городить, интерфейс DbSet и так хорош.

Я попытался сделать максимально абстрактный репозиторий который можно подменять в DI различными реализациями технологий хранения (SQL через EFCore, хранить в XML файле, хранить в NoSql).
Ниже приведу структуру проекта и код, прошу высказать свое мнение, Т.К. появился проект со сложным слоем данных и я опять раздумываю над Репозиторием.
Наверное подменять EfCoreRepository на другую систему хранения не придется, но все же хочется максимально независимо и абстрактно работать с данными.

Структура проекта

[image]

### Проект DAL.Abstract содержит:

`IGenericDataRepository.cs` - абстрактный интерфейс репозитория

```
    public interface IGenericDataRepository<T>
    {
        T GetById(int id);
        Task<T> GetByIdAsync(int id);

        T GetSingle(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate);
        Task<T> GetSingleAsync(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate);
        IEnumerable<T> GetWithInclude(params Expression<Func<T, object>>[] includeProperties); //?????

        IEnumerable<T> List();
        IEnumerable<T> List(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate);
        Task<IEnumerable<T>> ListAsync();
        Task<IEnumerable<T>> ListAsync(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate);

        int Count(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate);
        Task<int> CountAsync(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate);

        void Add(T entity);
        Task AddAsync(T entity);

        void AddRange(IEnumerable<T> entitys); 
        Task AddRangeAsync(IEnumerable<T> entitys); 

        void Delete(T entity);
        void Delete(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate);
        Task DeleteAsync(T entity);
        Task DeleteAsync(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate);

        void Edit(T entity);
        Task EditAsync(T entity);

        bool IsExist(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate);
        Task<bool> IsExistAsync(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate);
    }
```

`IRepository.cs` - Интерфейсы конкретных репозиториев.
                 Вдруг понадобится ооочень специфичный метод работы с данными для конкретного репозитория и чтобы не добавлять его в IGenericDataRepository.

```
public interface ISerialPortOptionRepository : IGenericDataRepository<SerialOption>
{  
}
public interface ITcpIpOptionRepository : IGenericDataRepository<TcpIpOption>
{
}

public interface IHttpOptionRepository : IGenericDataRepository<HttpOption>
{
}

public interface IExchangeOptionRepository : IGenericDataRepository<ExchangeOption>
{
}
public interface IDeviceOptionRepository : IGenericDataRepository<DeviceOption>
{
}
```

В папки `Entities` модель данных которые нужно сохранять в репозитории.
Модель чистая (СВОЙСТВА БЕЗ АТРИБУТОВ И ДОП. ПРИБЛУД СПЕЦИФИЧНЫХ ДЛЯ СИСТЕМЫ ХРАНЕНИЯ)

`DeviceOption.cs` - какая-то модель данных понятная для бизнес логики

```
    public class DeviceOption : EntityBase
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string TopicName4MessageBroker { get; set; }         
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public bool AutoBuild { get; set; }                        
        public bool AutoStart{ get; set; }                
        public List<string> ExchangeKeys { get; set; }
    }
```

### Проект `DAL.EFCore` содержит РЕАЛИЗАЦИЮ КОНКРЕТНОЙ ТЕХНОЛОГИИ ХРАНЕНИЯ

В папки `Entities` модель данных В КОТОРОЙ УДОБНО ХРАНИТЬ ДАННЫЕ ДЛЯ КОНКРЕТНОЙ ТЕХНОЛОГИИ (В ДАННОМ СЛУЧАЕ ДЛЯ `EFCore`).

`EfDeviceOption.cs` - та же модель (`DeviceOption`), только для системы хранения, в понятной для нее форме.

```
public class EfDeviceOption : IEntity
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [MaxLength(256)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [MaxLength(256)]
    public string TopicName4MessageBroker { get; set; }         

    [Required]
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public bool AutoBuild { get; set; }                         
    public bool AutoStart { get; set; }                        


    private string _exchangeKeysMetaData;
    [NotMapped]
    public string[] ExchangeKeys
    {
        get => _exchangeKeysMetaData.Split(';');
        set => _exchangeKeysMetaData = string.Join($"{';'}", value);
    }
}
```

`Context.cs` - контекст данных для EfCore.

```
public sealed class Context : Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext
{
    private readonly string _connStr;  // строка подключенния

    #region Reps

    public DbSet<EfSerialOption> SerialPortOptions { get; set; }
    public DbSet<EfTcpIpOption> TcpIpOptions { get; set; }
    public DbSet<EfHttpOption> HttpOptions { get; set; }
    public DbSet<EfDeviceOption> DeviceOptions { get; set; }
    public DbSet<EfExchangeOption> ExchangeOptions { get; set; }

    #endregion

    #region ctor

    public Context(string connStr)
    {
        _connStr = connStr;
        ChangeTracker.QueryTrackingBehavior = QueryTrackingBehavior.NoTracking;
        Database.EnsureCreated();
    }

    #endregion

    #region Config

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(_connStr);
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
       modelBuilder.ApplyConfiguration(new EfDeviceOptionConfig());
       modelBuilder.ApplyConfiguration(new EfExchangeOptionConfig());
       modelBuilder.ApplyConfiguration(new EfHttpOptionConfig());
       base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }

    #endregion
}
```

`DesignTimeDbContextFactory.cs` - фабрика создания контекста для системы МИГРАЦИЙ
`AutoMapperConfig.cs` - настройка маппинга МЕЖДУ МОДЕЛЬЮ `DAL.Abstract` И `DAL.EFCore`

В ПАПКЕ `Repository` РЕАЛИЗАЦИЯ КОНКРЕТНЫХ РЕПОЗИТОРИЕВ

`EfBaseRepository.cs` - базовый класс репозитория для EfCore

```
/// <summary>
/// Базовый тип репозитория для EntitiFramework
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="TDb">Тип в системе хранения</typeparam>
/// <typeparam name="TMap">Тип в бизнесс логики</typeparam>
public abstract class EfBaseRepository<TDb, TMap> : IDisposable
                                                    where TDb : class, IEntity
                                                    where TMap : class
{
    #region field
    protected readonly Context Context;
    protected readonly DbSet<TDb> DbSet;
    #endregion


    #region ctor
    protected EfBaseRepository(string connectionString)
    {
        Context = new Context(connectionString);
        DbSet = Context.Set<TDb>();
    }
    static EfBaseRepository()
    {
        AutoMapperConfig.Register();
    }
    #endregion


    #region CRUD
    protected TMap GetById(int id)
    {
        var efSpOption = DbSet.Find(id);
        var spOptions = AutoMapperConfig.Mapper.Map<TMap>(efSpOption);
        return spOptions;
    }

    protected async Task<TMap> GetByIdAsync(int id)
    {
        var efSpOption = await DbSet.FindAsync(id);
        var spOptions = AutoMapperConfig.Mapper.Map<TMap>(efSpOption);
        return spOptions;
    }

    protected TMap GetSingle(Expression<Func<TMap, bool>> predicate)
    {
        var efPredicate = AutoMapperConfig.Mapper.MapExpression<Expression<Func<TDb, bool>>>(predicate);
        var efSpOption = DbSet.SingleOrDefault(efPredicate);
        var spOption = AutoMapperConfig.Mapper.Map<TMap>(efSpOption);
        return spOption;
    }

    protected async Task<TMap> GetSingleAsync(Expression<Func<TMap, bool>> predicate)
    {
        var efPredicate = AutoMapperConfig.Mapper.MapExpression<Expression<Func<TDb, bool>>>(predicate);
        var efSpOption = await DbSet.SingleOrDefaultAsync(efPredicate);
        var spOption = AutoMapperConfig.Mapper.Map<TMap>(efSpOption);
        return spOption;
    }

    // ... И ДРУГИЕ МЕТОДЫ РЕПОЗИТОРИЯ
    #endregion


    #region Methode
    private IQueryable<TDb> Include(params Expression<Func<TDb, object>>[] includeProperties)
    {
        IQueryable<TDb> query = DbSet.AsNoTracking();
        return includeProperties.Aggregate(query, (current, includeProperty) => current.Include(includeProperty));
    }
    #endregion


    #region Disposable
    public void Dispose()
    {
        Context?.Dispose();
    }
    #endregion
}
```

`EfDeviceOptionRepository.cs` - КОНКРЕТНЫЙ РЕПОЗИТОРИЙ РЕАЛИЗУЮЩИЙ `IDeviceOptionRepository`

```
public class EfExchangeOptionRepository : EfBaseRepository<EfExchangeOption, ExchangeOption>, IExchangeOptionRepository
{
    #region ctor

    public EfExchangeOptionRepository(string connectionString) : base(connectionString)
    {
    }

    #endregion



    #region CRUD

    public new ExchangeOption GetById(int id)
    {
        return base.GetById(id);
    }

    public new async Task<ExchangeOption> GetByIdAsync(int id)
    {
        return await base.GetByIdAsync(id);
    }

    public new ExchangeOption GetSingle(Expression<Func<ExchangeOption, bool>> predicate)
    {
        return base.GetSingle(predicate);
    }

     // ... И ДРУГИЕ МЕТОДЫ РЕПОЗИТОРИЯ (ЕCЛИ protected ДОCТУП В БАЗОВОМ КЛАССЕ ПОМЕНЯТЬ НА public то можно использовать базовую реализацию, не замещая метод через new)

    #endregion
}
```

### Проект `BL.Services` содержит различные сервисы бизнес логики и один из сервисов объединяет работу с репозиториями предоставляя удобный интерфейс.

`MediatorForOptions.cs` - КАКАЯ-ТО ВЫСОКОУРОВНЕВАЯ ЛОГИКА ДЛЯ РАБОТЫ С РЕПОЗИТОРИЯМИ

```
/// <summary>
/// Сервис объединяет работу с репозиотриями опций для устройств.
/// DeviceOption + ExchangeOption + TransportOption.
/// </summary>
public class MediatorForOptions
{
    #region fields
    private readonly IDeviceOptionRepository _deviceOptionRep;
    private readonly IExchangeOptionRepository _exchangeOptionRep;
    private readonly ISerialPortOptionRepository _serialPortOptionRep;
    private readonly ITcpIpOptionRepository _tcpIpOptionRep;
    private readonly IHttpOptionRepository _httpOptionRep;
    #endregion


    #region ctor
    public MediatorForOptions(IDeviceOptionRepository deviceOptionRep,
        IExchangeOptionRepository exchangeOptionRep,
        ISerialPortOptionRepository serialPortOptionRep,
        ITcpIpOptionRepository tcpIpOptionRep,
        IHttpOptionRepository httpOptionRep)
    {
        _deviceOptionRep = deviceOptionRep;
        _exchangeOptionRep = exchangeOptionRep;
        _serialPortOptionRep = serialPortOptionRep;
        _tcpIpOptionRep = tcpIpOptionRep;
        _httpOptionRep = httpOptionRep;
    }
    #endregion


    #region Methode
     //МЕТОДЫ ОБЪЕДИНЯЮЩИЕ РАБОТУ С РЕПОЗИТОРИЯМИ 
    #endregion
}
```

### Проект `WebServer` - Точка входа в приложение (`WebApi`) использует `Autofac` как `DI` контейнер.

`RepositoryAutofacModule.cs`   - модуль регистрации DI зависимостей для резолва репозиториев (выбирает конкретную систему хранения)

```
public class RepositoryAutofacModule : Module
    {
        private readonly string _connectionString;


        #region ctor
        public RepositoryAutofacModule(string connectionString)
        {
            _connectionString = connectionString;
        }
        #endregion


        protected override void Load(ContainerBuilder builder)
        {
            builder.RegisterType<EfSerialPortOptionRepository>().As<ISerialPortOptionRepository>()
                .WithParameters(new List<Parameter>
                {
                    new NamedParameter("connectionString", _connectionString),
                })
                .InstancePerLifetimeScope();

            builder.RegisterType<EfTcpIpOptionRepository>().As<ITcpIpOptionRepository>()
                .WithParameters(new List<Parameter>
                {
                    new NamedParameter("connectionString", _connectionString),
                })
                .InstancePerLifetimeScope();

            builder.RegisterType<EfHttpOptionRepository>().As<IHttpOptionRepository>()
                .WithParameters(new List<Parameter>
                {
                    new NamedParameter("connectionString", _connectionString),
                })
                .InstancePerLifetimeScope();

            builder.RegisterType<EfExchangeOptionRepository>().As<IExchangeOptionRepository>()
                .WithParameters(new List<Parameter>
                {
                    new NamedParameter("connectionString", _connectionString),
                })
                .InstancePerLifetimeScope();

            builder.RegisterType<EfDeviceOptionRepository>().As<IDeviceOptionRepository>()
                .WithParameters(new List<Parameter>
                {
                    new NamedParameter("connectionString", _connectionString),
                })
                .InstancePerLifetimeScope();
        }
    }
```

`MediatorsAutofacModule.cs` - модуль регистрации DI зависимостей для резолва сервисов бизнес логики.

```
MediatorsAutofacModule.cs   
{
    protected override void Load(ContainerBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.RegisterType<MediatorForOptions>().InstancePerDependency();
    }
}
```

ВСЕ-------------------------

т.е. я использую `MediatorForOptions` для работы с опциями везде по проекту.

```
МИНУСЫ которые вижу я 

1. МНОООГО маппинга - т.к. у каждой системы хранения своя модель данных, но система хранения обязуется работать в общих типах (Entities из DAL.Abstract).

2. Запросы к БД сложно оптимизировать т.к. наружу торчит не IQuereble, а Ienumerable. Следовательно каждый метод репозитория выполняет какое-то 1 действие и их нельзя объединит. (паттерн UnitOfWork не использую).

3. В новой версии 2.1 EfCore появилась система регистрации контекста в ПУЛЕ (services.AddDbContextPool(...)), вместо perScope. Что должно увеличить производительность. Но в моей модели где я контекст создаю сам, эту фишку НЕЛЬЗЯ использовать.

4. Довольно много кода.
```

Стоит ли вообще заморачиваться?

И что можно улучшить?

Comment: Спасибо, почитаю. Хотел на будущее использовать dapper, а Ef только для миграций. Я так понял что у Mark Seeman  вся фишка в использовании DI для такой реализации DAL?

Comment: Меня еще смущает постоянный 2-у сторонний маппинг, EF и так не быстрый а тут еще и постоянные аллокации в памяти временных объектов. Я так понял самое простое использовать использовать зависимость от Context EF сразу в слое, бизнес логики?

Comment: Отлично, почитаю. Спасибо большое.

Comment: Меня одолевают точно такие же сомнения, как и автора. Сам нагородил похожую структуру, сделал фабрику для создания доменных объектов (как в вопросе - "чистых моделей") из view моделей. Обратный маппинг (domain to view model) делаю автомаппером. Но больше всего меня смущает, что при сложных моделях, где некоторые свойства - другие модели, можно часто словить что то типа dublicate primary key exception. Я пробовал добавлять репозитории через AddTransient<,>(), через AddScoped<,>() в Startup.cs. Все один результат. И да, производительность тоже страдает. Думаю, отказаться от них(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Из подобных приложений на гитхабе сразу вспоминается [RealWorld example app](https://github.com/gothinkster/aspnetcore-realworld-example-app.git), хотя вообще вариаций шаблона масса.

У Марка Симана ( Mark Seeman) в его книге Dependency injection CSharp показан вариант, как в приложении совсем отвязаться от EF - и я как-то ради любопытства собрал приложение, полностью отвязанное от DAL (солюшен, в котором было две реализации dal - одна на EF, другая на dapper, переключаться можно было в рантайме, а студия показывала что проект с exe не зависел от этих двух). Так что если хотите - отвязаться можно практически полностью, было бы желание.

По поводу DbSet вы правильно пишете, это ведь уже готовая реализация паттерна репозиторий от майкрософт и он уже есть в EF. Да и в книгах/статях такое много где проскальзывает, плюс на so обсуждалось в комментариях к вопросам/ответам (можете поискать у PashaPash подобное - в моих и Bald вопросах). Я когда-то раньше предпочитал IEnumerable и IReadOnlyCollection только за то, что меньше зависимостей от EF. У Симана в статьях много порой спорных моментов, поэтому лучше составьте своё мнение. Или даже так: его не понимают те, кто не особо любит DDD и предпочитает готовые либы от майкрософт не выходя особо за рамки типовых решений. Я думаю, что с вашим подходом вам наоборот многое понравится. И ещё - вы скоро придёте к тому, что EF даже и для миграций не особо-то и поймёте прелесть подхода Database First (который в core практически полностью под нож пустили)

О маппинге. От маппинга при подобном подходе никуда не деться. Я видел много вариантов реализаций паттерна и есть только один способ (неправильный, разумеется) не делать постоянный маппинг - это когда одни и те же классы используются и как доменные объекты и как объекты DAL. Однако если вы читали "Чистую архитектуру" дядюшки Боба и понимаете, что такое архитектурные слои и как выглядят архитектурные границы -- то должны понимать, что либо вы чётко обозначаете архитектурную границу и тогда - только конвертация из одних классов в другие на границе (маппинг, либо вручную писать, либо на автомапперы полагаться), либо стирание этой границы.

Comment: было бы крайне интересно услышать почему Database First *лучше*, кстати и вопрос [есть](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/902802/179270)

Comment: Отлично!!!!!!!!!!!!!