# Подходы EF в Asp net core

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

Как я понимаю, есть 3 подхода в ef: Code-First,Model-First,Database-First.В чем преимущество подходов (к примеру code-first), если можно к примеру просто создать бд в **asp .net core** через обычные миграции(впринципе как и сделали разработчики с базовой структурой auth) ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Когда вы используете базу, ее схема неизбежно должна быть описана три раза: в самой базе данных (Database), в  программной мета-модели (Model) вашей библиотеки для доступа к БД и в виде структуры классов (Code). В зависимости от того, какая из этих частей создается первой - и выделяется три подхода.

**Code First** - это и есть подход, при котором вы *"просто создаете бд через обычные миграции"*. При этом подходе вы как программист пишете классы сущностей, а EF за вас строит модель и создает базу.

**Model First** - это устаревший подход, при котором вы как программист составляете edmx-модель в визуальном дизайнере, а EF за вас генерирует вам классы и базу данных. В EF Core он уже не поддерживается, и правильно: визуальный редактор модели тормозил, лагал, глючил, и просто был неудобным. Класс, который пишется за минуту, в визуальном редакторе составляется минут пятнадцать. В 2018м году нет никаких причин использовать подход "сначала модель" в новых проектах.

**Database First** - это классический подход, при котором сначала мудрый DBA (администратор баз данных) составляет БД, а потом вы как программист используете ее в своей программе, автоматически сгенерировав либо вручную написав модель и классы по ней. Этот подход имеет смысл использовать если у вас уже есть готовая БД, либо если требуются серьезные оптимизации на стороне базы (хранимые процедуры, индексированные виды, триггеры).

При необходимости между подходами не так уж и сложно перейти, поэтому рекомендую начинать с Code First, а на Database First переходить когда Code First уже больше "не лезет".

Также отмечу, что подход Database First одним только EF не ограничивается, и его может оказаться целесообразнее использовать с другими инструментами: Linq2Sql, Linq2Db, Dapper

Comment: Поправьте, если неправильно говорю. Но можно ведь в .net core, обойтись без этих подходов, и создать просто миграцию вручную. И например в методе Up (там зависимость MigrationBuilder), все прописать, и избежать этих подходов. И потом также выполнить "Migration-update"

Comment: @nikitaAbramov если вы "просто создадите миграцию вручную" ничего больше не меняя - у вас будет ошибочная программа, потому что код и модель разойдутся с базой данных. Вам нужно будет обязательно поправить структуру классов. Так вот, если вы сначала добавили миграцию, а потом классы сущностей - это Database First без автоматизации. Если вы сделали наоборот - это Code First.

Answer (score 2):

Code First форсируется корпорацией microsoft как наиболее рекомендуемый и прогрессивный подход. Этот подход очень хорош для быстрого старта/прототипирования приложения, хотя по мере роста вы будете всё больше упираться в его ограничения. Разработка реально много быстрее.

Из минусов:

- не всё к сожалению можно описать кодом (а некоторые вещи ещё не успели/не стали портировать в core - приходится писать самому), некоторые вещи удобнее и проще описать на языке самой базы данных - SQL, который для этого и спроектирован.
- EF linq to database генерирует многие запросы не самым оптимальным способом и для того, чтобы выжать по-максимуму приходится переходить на plain sql запросы. В общем-то хорошему программисту это мешает не сильно, но у начинающих часто возникает соблазн "а зачем вообще знать SQL, мы просто будем использовать Code First".

DbFirst в Core [урезан](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/efcore/create-model-for-existing-database-in-ef-core.aspx) до "контекст в первый раз генерируем из базы, а потом миграциями" (в EF6 был полноценный Db First). (Выкрутиться можно [так](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1012646/213987))

В плюсах подхода:

- правильная методология (база описывается отдельно от кода, а DDD'шники отдельно подчёркивают, что начинать нужно не с базы, а с моделей предметной сущности) и явно прочерченная граница архитектурных слоёв приложения.
- возможность выжать по-максимуму скорости за счёт низкоуровневой работы с БД

В минусах:

- подход требует больше знаний от разработчиков
- банально медленнее в работе

Ссылки по теме:

- [«Истина в последней инстанции» или зачем нужен Database First Design](https://habr.com/post/413597/)
- [Database as Сode. Копаем глубже](https://habr.com/company/croc/blog/333376/)
- [Я не буду учить твой Garbage Query Language](https://habr.com/post/422667/)

Comment: *"DbFirst в Core урезан до "контекст в первый раз генерируем из базы, а потом миграциями" "* - простите, но что мешает каждый раз генерировать его из базы, а миграции выключить?

Comment: И да, по приведенным ссылкам сами посты читать не стоит - там самое полезное в комментариях :-)

Comment: @PavelMayorov Насколько я понимаю - так сложнее поддерживать много клиентов с разными версиями схемы. Один сидит на одной версии ПО, другой - на другой.

Comment: Напротив, в условиях разных версий схемы (но общей базы) только подход Database First и работает. При подходе Code First клиенты "тянут одеяло на себя" - пытаются мигрировать базу и падают если не получается это сделать.

Comment: @PavelMayorov Я имею ввиду не энтерпрайз, где зачастую один инстанс приложения - а клиента в терминах продажников: одна компания купила продукт версии 3.2.1 и база у неё этой версии, другой купил через месяц 3.2.2 и обновляться до 3.2.3 никто из обоих не хочет.

Comment: и в чем тут проблема?