# Обновление модели в EF Core при подходе Db-First

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

Я использовал в проекте EntityFramework Core с подходом database first и создал модель данных [по документации](https://docs.efproject.net/en/latest/platforms/aspnetcore/existing-db.html#reverse-engineer-your-model).

Но я не знаю, как обновить модель, когда база изменилась.

В EF 6 был инструмент обновления модели:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Который запускал отдельный Wizard:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Похоже, что такого инструмента больше нет.

<sub>Свободный перевод вопроса [How to update the model when using database first approach](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38739950/5752652) от участника  [@witson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6510371/witson).</sub>

Comment: ассоциация: https://stackoverflow.com/q/38739950

Answer (score 2):

Подобного инструмента в EF Core нет (на текущий момент EF Core 2.2 и похоже не будет [в планах как минимум](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-3.0/breaking-changes) до EF Core 3.0)

Что можно сделать?

Вы можете заново запустить скафолд модели: ту же самую команду, которой изначально генерировали, только с добавлением ключа `-Force` -- это приведёт к тому, что содержимое модели будет перезаписано поверх изначальной модели.

Например, используя Package Manager Console команда будет вида:

```
Scaffold-DbContext "Server=(localdb)\v11.0;Database=Blogging;Trusted_Connection=True;" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -OutputDir Models -Force
```

Альтернативно, используя CLI команда будет вида:

```
dotnet ef dbcontext scaffold "Server=(localdb)\v11.0;Database=Blogging;Trusted_Connection=True;" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -o Models -f
```

## Дополнительный совет

Если вы постоянно обновляете модель, вот удобный способ облегчить процесс.

Зайдите в меню **Tools** > **External Tools**, затем кликните **Add** и заполните параметры следующим образом:

---

**Title**:

```
Update DbContext
```

**Command**:

```
dotnet.exe
```

**Arguments**:

```bsh
ef dbcontext scaffold "your-connection-string" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer --output-dir=Models --force
```

**Initial directory**:

```
$(ProjectDir)
```

---

Опционально можно поставить галку "Use Output window", после чего нажмите **Apply** и **OK**.

Когда вы снова зайдёте в меню **Tools**, в нём появится ваш новый пункт меню -- остаётся просто нажать, чтобы запустить обновление модели!

<sub>Свободный перевод ответа [How to update the model when using database first approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38784385/5752652) от участника  [@Mike Brind](https://stackoverflow.com/users/134725/mike-brind) и ответа [How to update the model when using database first approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51574836/5752652) от участника  [@Yom S.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3634538/yom-s).</sub>