# Как обновить модели в ASP.NET CORE

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

Как обновить модели в .NET CORE, если вы добавили таблицы или изменили их в базе данных. Я нашел миграцию но оно работает наоборот.

Comment: Какая СУБД? Какая ORM?

Comment: MS SQL server, Entity Framework Core

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Обновление модели в EF Core при подходе Db-First](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1012646/%d0%9e%d0%b1%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%b2-ef-core-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b4%d1%85%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b5-db-first)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для того, что бы создать модели из базы данных в EF.Core используется команда [Scaffold-DbContext](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/ef/core/managing-schemas/scaffolding?tabs=vs) .

Есть два основных способа вызвать команду: консоль диспетчера пакетов Nuget и простая командная строка. Они немного отличаются регистром и дефисами.

командная строка

```
dotnet ef dbcontext scaffold "Data Source=(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB;Initial Catalog=Chinook" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer
```

диспетчер пакетов

```
Scaffold-DbContext 'Data Source=(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB;Initial Catalog=Chinook' Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer
```

В вышеуказанных примерах строка подключения содержится в команде. Как правило, это приводит к тому что строка подключения скопируется в контекст базы данных. А оттуда в систему управления версиями, а потом в удаленные репозитории СУВ. Если хотите этого избежать, можно пользоваться именованными строками подключения и секретами пользователя.

Comment: Спасибо большое за ответ! но мне хотелось бы узнать именно как обновить модели если я изменил таблицы в БД вручную (добавил столбец).  Перезаписать модели тоже не вариант.

Comment: в конце команды добавляется ключ `--force` или `-Force`

Comment: Большое спасибо все работает.